# How to save/record live streaming video feed in App Inventor app?

Tags: android, image, video, app-inventor

I have created an android app using App Inventor where it displays live video feed in image component. I wanted to record that video feed and save.
Also to take images.
Is there any way to do that in App Inventor?

[image]

Comment: Show what you have tried.

Comment: I am uploading a screenshot on google drive. pls wait

Comment: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1hZt_vIfGCUmHO_C76Xf_GLf75XI_gck9

Comment: to take images try the [screenshot extension](https://puravidaapps.com/screenshot.php)

Comment: @Taifun thanks for your edits and extension but is there a way for recording on screen video?

Comment: currently not, but you might find an Android library and then you might be able to create an App Inventor extension to do this... more information about how to create an extension see the [App Inventor Extensions document](http://ai2.appinventor.mit.edu/reference/other/extensions.html), 
however that will be more advanced and will require some Java skills...